# Guacamole - RDP file transfer error

Tags: linux, nginx, tomcat, rdp

I would appreciate if somebody point me in a right direction with the following problem.

Task:
Configure RDP file transfer via Apache Guacamole.

Problem:

```
a) Within RDP session (logged in as Administrator) I have an error when I try to download file from 
   my workstation to Win server 2012r2  - "You do not have permission to upload this file. 
   If you require access, please check with your system settings"
b) Within the same RDP session I am getting error when I try to download file to created virtual 
   drive (configured within Guacamole server in "Connection Settings") - "Could not find this item. 
   This is no longer located in "C:'temp""
```

Configuration on Guacamole server admin console:

> "Connections  >> Edit Connection  >> Device Redirection"
> Options chosen:
> - "Enable drive: 'checked'"
> - "Drive name:  'DropHere'"
> - "Drive path:  'C:\temp'"
> - "Automatically create drive - 'checked'"

> Guacamole server (+ Nginx and Tomcat) configured in DMZ zone.
> There are no problems in RDP connection to any server, port 3389 is open.

My feeling that error has something to do with Nginx or Tomcat configuration but RDP sessions themselves.
Please help !

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

maybe too late for answering, but the "Drive path" is on the Unix server.
I use this : /tmp/${GUAC_USERNAME}
But you can use whatever path you need provided it exists.
++